# How can I get the nth occurrence of a searchvalue in a string with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

For example, string is "staaaae", If searchValue is "aa", n=2, then 3 will return.

Comment: This is not what regular expressions are for

Comment: [What is the *real* problem that you are trying to solve?](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of regex itself, but depending on your language you can get this information.

For one thing I have to correct you. The start index for the second match is **4** and not 3 (Standard regex matching behaviour)

```
staaaae
  ^^  first match
    ^^   second match
```

The pattern continues to search after the first match, so the matches do not overlap.

**Perl**

In Perl for example its no problem.

> In addition to what was matched, Perl (since 5.6.0) also provides the
>   positions of what was matched as contents of the @- and @+ arrays.
>   $-[0] is the position of the start of the entire match and $+[0] is
>   the position of the end. Similarly, $-[n] is the position of the start
>   of the $n match and $+[n] is the position of the end. If $n is
>   undefined, so are $-[n] and $+[n] .

cited from [Perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Position-information)

so in Perl the information you want would be in `$-[n]`.

**c#/.net**

In .net its also no problem. Only a bit more effort than in Perl.

The class `Match` returns you also the index of the match, but it matches only one at a time, so you have to go through a loop to get all matches.

```
string input = "staaaae";
string pattern = @"aa";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
int count = 0;

while (match.Success)
{
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' was found the {1} timein the source code at position {2}.",
    match.Value, count, match.Index);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The start index of the second match would be 3, if matches overlap. Perl doesn't dictate the domain of the problem. The question is a very ambiguous [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: @Johnsyweb yes, if matches overlap. In regex itself, they don't. I think there are again language specific features (in some languages) where you can set the start index of each search (I never used it) but that would mean some more coding, and I tried to explain the standard behaviour.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, probably you are right and that is not his real problem, but anyway I find this a quite good/interesting question.